# Do sql request if there are no erros / Retrieve data

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In my Excel VBA code, I open a connection with other workbook.

```
  With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        .CommandTimeout = 500
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & path & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;Readonly=true"";"
    .Open
```

I want to do this kind of line :

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("H306:307").CopyFromRecordset .Execute("select * from [values$S8:S8]")
```

But, it is possible that the sheet "values" doesn't exist, it is why I want to do this line only if there are no erros or if "values" exist, but I don't know how do that.

Comment: If you use T-SQL you can check the count of your select and then `RAISERROR` if it is 0.

Comment: Dim count As Integer
count = .Execute("select COUNT(*) from [values$S8:S8]") something like that?

Comment: No that way you will get the count only. You need to select as 'smth' and then check count(smth).

Comment: Do you have an example with my values pleasE?

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to check whether a worksheet exists, then do it. And forget about the SQL, it is non-relevant:

```
Public Function worksheetExists(wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet) As Boolean    
    worksheetExists = IsError(wb.sh.Range("A1"))    
End Function
```

And if you want to put the openning of the file in the function, then:

```
Public Function worksheetExists(path As String, sh As Worksheet) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo worksheetExists_Error

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    worksheetExists = IsError(wb.sh.Range("A1"))

    wb.Close False

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

worksheetExists_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") "

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `On Error Resume Next` really carefully, because it would ignore any error. However, you can do it on one line and put `On Error GoTo 0`, which stops the action. At the end, before assigning values to the new worksheet, check whether `rs is not Nothing`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim path As String: path = "C:\Source.xlsx"
    Dim rs As Object

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        .CommandTimeout = 500
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
                    & path & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;Readonly=true"";"
        .Open

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rs = .Execute("SELECT * FROM [Sheet12$A1:B4]")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
            .CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```